# I decided / I thought

Tags: grammar, thought

I was writing to my supervisor today asking for a day off. Here is what I wrote "Dr, I had an accident yesterday. Luckily it wasn't major. But I am not feeling fully recovered today. So I decided to stay at home" but after sending the message it didn't sound write to me. since I was using WhatsApp I deleted the message before she read it. And this is what I wrote later which sounded better in my ears: "Dr, I had an accident yesterday. Luckily it wasn't major. But I am not feeling fully recovered today. So I thought I should stay at home".

The problem is I don't know why my first message didn't sound as good as the second one. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are fine. The reason why 'decided' sounds weird to you is that 'thought' makes it seem less planned. You didn't plan to stay at home, you thought maybe you should stay at home considering how physically unfit you feel. 'decided' places emphasis on your action thereafter and 'thought' places emphasis on what you previously explained.
Just comment if this doesn't make sense.